# how to arrange a array in custom format using php

Tags: php, arrays

i would like to display a array in custom format below is my array

```
name: {
[0]=> ramesh
[1]=> kumar
[2]=> suresh

      }

price: {
[0]=> 150
[1]=> 200
[2]=> 126

}

quantity: {
[0]=> 1
[1]=> 2
[2]=> 1

}

total: {
[0]=> 150
[1]=> 400
[2]=> 126

}
```

i want print above array in below order.

```
name          price    quantity  total

ramesh        150        1        150
kumar         200        2        400 
suresh        126        1        126
```

print_r will print the hole array. but i want to display in order. how can i do this using php.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) and [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) are what you need

Comment: is your initial array a multidimensional array? you should use `var_dump($array)` or `print_r($array)` to show us the actual content of your array or arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTML:

```
$arrays = array($name, $price, $quantity, $total);
echo "<table>";
for($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++){
    echo "<td>";
    foreach($arrays as $arr) echo "<tr>", $arr[$i], "</tr>";
    echo "</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

If you want plaintext: use [`str_pad`](http://php.net/str-pad). First count the maximum number of characters in a column with `max(array_map("strlen", $array))`, then pad each cell with `str_pad($value, $maxLength` to align.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101699/discussion-between-asesha-george-and-pemap-modder).

Comment: just correct to $arrays = array($name, $price, $quantity, $total);

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>quantity</th><th>Total</th></tr>";
for($i = 0; $i< 3;  $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>$name[$i]</td><td>$price[$i]</td><td>$quantity[$i]</td><td>$total[$i]</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```